# Autohotkey script to emulate krunner

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

Is there a way to emulate krunner with Autohotkey? The idea is to press ALT+F2, for example, type the name of the program and it would search for the installed programs and start it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that already with the `start menu` from the windows key

click the `windows` key > type the name of the program > press `enter` to launch it